# a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it in bluebird

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm using `bluebird` in my app and I use babel to compile my code into es5. However, I always got this warning and I've checked that every pieces of Promise has `return` value.

Here's my code:

```
Promise.promisifyAll(fs);

use.login().then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
  doSomething('../test.png');
});

function doSomething(filepath) {
  return fs.readFileAsync(filepath).then((bufs) => (
      doPost(url, bufs, filepath)
        .then((res) => (
          res.error ? Promise.reject(res.error) : Promise.resolve(res))
        )
  )).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    return err;
  });
}


function doPost(url, bufs = null, filepath = null) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => (
    unirest.post(url)
      .headers(config.Headers)
      .timeout(120000)
      .field(bufs)
      .attach('files', filepath)
      .end((res) => (
        res.error ? reject(res.error) : resolve(res)
      ))
  ));
}
```

Details of error messages:

```
Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it
at doSomething (/home/test/Documents/test/lib/abc.js:2:27)
// This line number is referred to the compiled code which is equal to line 4:12 in the above code
```

Comment: Where are you calling `doSomething`? Is that your whole code?

Comment: @Bergi No, that is not my whole code but I only got the warning in the above code. I will call `doSomething` when I need to read a file, ex. `doSomething('../test.png')`

Comment: I meant that maybe you are calling `doSomething` from a promise handler that didn't `return` anything. Is that the whole call stack of the warning? It would be helpful if you could show the whole code.

Comment: OH!!! @Bergi yes, you're right !!! I didn't `return` anything in my doSomething call stack!! The warning is gone after I add `return` after `doSomething`. Thanks a lot !! I've updated the code above to show my code which will cause warning.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Bergi that I didn't check the promise stack where I call `doSomething` so the warning disappeared after I modify my code as below

```
use.login().then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
  doSomething('../test.png');
  return null; // Add this line to make promise return anything, then the warning gone
});
```